Selecting 1 of 3 colums as value for new column, based on criteria in row
So I have data with the following format



Name
Duration
y_dur1
y_dur2
y_dur3




John
dur1
.01
.02
.02


Mike
dur2
.05
.03
.04


Chris
dur3
.03
.04
.08



I want to create a column y that takes from y1 y2 or y3 depending on the entry in the table



Name
Duration
y_dur1
y_dur2
y_dur3
y




John
dur1
.01
.02
.02
.01


Mike
dur2
.05
.03
.04
.03


Chris
dur3
.03
.04
.08
.08



I want to do this in the cleanest way possible. I have to actually do this for about 30 columns. 5 groups of 6. This is more simplified. My current code looks like this:
df = pd.read_csv(path)

cols = df.columns
dur_cols = pd.Series([col for col in df.columns if "_Dur" in col])

val_cols = dur_cols.replace('\d',"", regex=True)

val_cols.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)



for col in val_cols:
    df[col] = np.where(df["Duration_to_use"]=="dur1",df[col+"1"],np.where(df["Duration_to_use"]=="dur2",df[col+"2"],df[col+"3"]))

I think this works, but I want to find a better way.

The official approach to that is called "indexing lookup", see here and official documentation.

In your case: idx, cols = pd.factorize('y_'+df['Duration']) ; df['y'] = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
